# Can't change Replication properties for Linux VM in Azure Site Recovery

Tags: azure-site-recovery

We replicete some Windows and Linux VMs from Hyper-V to Azure
As a part of recovery preparation we need to change VMs params, e.g. size, nsg, resource group to be recovered into (different from ASR vault RG) via `Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem` cmdlet

For windows it works well, but for Linux we're getting `Failed to update the LicenseType for the physical or virtual machine.`
We don't need to change anything related to license, just RG to be recovered into

Why this issue is happening and how can we workaround it?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to specify param `-LicenseType` to be `NoLicenseType`